# Ionic: Unable to click into <a> element inside <ion-checkbox>

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a TOS agreement field inside my app, using the following code:

```
<ion-checkbox style="text-align:center" ng-model="signup.tospp">I agree to the <a href="../man/TOS">Terms of Service</a></ion-checkbox>
```

But I don't know why I don't get redirected to the TOS file (as refered by the  element).

So what's wrong here? is there any possibility to fix that?

Comment: What happens when you click on the TOS ?

Comment: @Habkamas Only the checkbox gets checked. but nothing else happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, and after looking at the following that solution: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-checkbox-with-an-external-link/25335.

I was able to solve my problem, using the following code:

-CSS:

```
.item-checkbox .checkbox {
      right: auto !important;
      }
```

-HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center" class="item item-checkbox">
          <label class="checkbox">
        <input ng-model="data.tospp" type="checkbox">
          </label>
I agree to the <a ng-click="tos()" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>
        </div>
```